# In core java, While getting input from user and inserting it into msql database, it shows error sql error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, inputstream

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
import java.sql.*;    
public class Complete {    
public static void main(String args[])    
{    
    System.out.println("Welcome to Your database");    
    try    
    {    
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);    
        System.out.println("Enter you First Name");    
        String f_name=keyboard.nextLine();     
        System.out.println("Enter your Last Name");    
        String l_name=keyboard.nextLine();    
        System.out.println("Welcome"+ " "+ f_name +" "+l_name);    

        System.out.println("Enter your Phone number");    
        String phno=keyboard.nextLine();    

        System.out.println("Enter your email id");    
        String email=keyboard.nextLine();    

        System.out.println("Enter your current city");    
        String city=keyboard.nextLine();    

        System.out.println("Enter you current State");    
        String state=keyboard.nextLine();    

        System.out.println("Enter you pin code");       
        String pin=keyboard.nextLine();    

        System.out.println("------------------------");    
        System.out.println("Your Details are following.");    

        System.out.println("Name :"+ " "+f_name +" "+ l_name);    
        System.out.println("Phone :"+ " "+phno);    
        System.out.println("Email :"+ " "+email);    
        System.out.println("City :"+ " "+city);    
        System.out.println("State :"+ " "+state);    
        System.out.println("PIN code :"+ " "+pin);    




        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");      

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/checking","root","lenovo");      
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();      

        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into empdetails(first_name,last_name,phone,email,city,state,pin) values(f_name, l_name, phno, email, city, state, pin)");      
        System.out.println("All Right , We got your entry");    



    }    
    catch(Exception e)    
    {System.out.println(e);}    
    finally{    
        System.out.println("Thanks for using our code");    
    }    
}    
}
```

basically i want to get input form user and store it in mysql database, 
While executing this code in eclipse IDE, it shows following error,

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'f_name' in 'field list'

Comment: What is `f_name`? What do you think it is referring to? Why do you think so? (This applies to all of those names in the SQL query.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL string has no knowledge of Java variables declared.  You cannot refer to Java variables in the SQL string.

Instead, use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and use `?` characters as placeholders for values.  Before executing, call `setString` or `setInt` (or `set[Xyz]` for other data types) to set the values of these placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

stmt.executeUpdate("insert into

```
empdetails(first_name,last_name,phone,email,city,state,pin) 

        values(f_name, l_name, phno, email, city, state, pin)");
```

this executeUpdate method at runtime , expects sql query with values to be inserted.

but you have directly mentioned java variables inside values() which is not at all understandable to SQL , because it expects values to be in quotes.

so better go with prepared statement to bind those values at runtime like below

```
preparedStmt.setString(1, f_name);
preparedStmt.setString(2, l_name);
preparedStmt.setString(3, phno);
.......



preparedStmt.executeUpdate("insert into empdetails(first_name,last_name,phone,email,city,state,pin) values

    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 1):

The variables that hold the values to be inserted should be passed as follows (with single quotes around them since they hold string values):

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into empdetails(first_name,last_name,phone,email,city,state,pin) values('" + f_name + "', '" + l_name + "', '" + phno + "', '" + email + "', '" + city + "', '" + state + "', '" + pin +"')");
```

A better way is to use a `PreparedStatement` and put `?` parameter placeholders in the SQL statement, which you can bind to your variables:

```
preparedStmt.executeUpdate("insert into empdetails(first_name,last_name,phone,email,city,state,pin) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

preparedStmt.setString(1, f_name);
preparedStmt.setString(2, l_name);
...
```

Comment: That would probably work, but it is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.